# Reading DWARF debug information from PE file on Windows with libdwarf

Tags: windows, debug-symbols, dwarf

`mingw` writes debug information to output executable file in DWARF format.

I need to parse this debug information. I've tried to adopt `libdwarf` but it seems to be able to read files in ELF format only. At the same time `mingw` places debug information to several PE sections.

Is there any way to pass raw data from these sections to `libdwarf` to read debug information?

Comment: libdwarf recently added support for [PE executables](https://www.prevanders.net/dwarf.html#libdwarf-20190104). I just tried dwarfdump of the latest version on a PE file, and it's working fine.

Comment: gdb under Cygwin does it somehow.